# Cubemapping with GLSL

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl

I tried cubemapping with GLSL. However, the object is black.

Why is the object unabled to shade?

Supplementary:

- Image can be read.
- projectionMatrix, viewMatrix and baseColor are working.

  ```
  glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 1, &_texture);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); // add
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, _texture);
  QImage posx;
  bool complateLoadCubeMapPosX = posx.load(("D:/posx.jpg"));
  assert(complateLoadCubeMapPosX);

  QImage negx;
  bool complateLoadCubeMapNegX = negx.load(("D:/negx.jpg"));
  assert(complateLoadCubeMapNegX);

  QImage posy;
  bool complateLoadCubeMapPosY = posy.load(("D:/posy.jpg"));
  assert(complateLoadCubeMapPosY);

  QImage negy;
  bool complateLoadCubeMapNegY = negy.load(("D:/negy.jpg"));
  assert(complateLoadCubeMapNegY);

  QImage posz;
  bool complateLoadCubeMapPosZ = posz.load(("D:/posz.jpg"));
  assert(complateLoadCubeMapPosZ);

  QImage negz;
  bool complateLoadCubeMapNegZ = negz.load(("D:/negz.jpg"));
  assert(complateLoadCubeMapNegZ);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);     // add
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);     // add
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  // add
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  // add
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  // add
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, posx.width(), posx.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, posx.bits());
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL_RGB, negx.width(), negx.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, negx.bits());
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, posy.width(), posy.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, posy.bits());
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL_RGB, negy.width(), negy.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, negy.bits());
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, posz.width(), posz.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, posz.bits());
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL_RGB, negz.width(), negz.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, negz.bits());

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // add
  MaterialManager::getInstance().createProgram("cubemap");
  ```

Rendering code:

```
    GLuint program = MaterialManager::getInstance().getShader("cubemap");
    glUseProgram(program);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "projMat"), 1, GL_FALSE, projectionMatrix.data());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(program, "viewMat"), 1, GL_FALSE, viewMatrix.data());
    glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(program, "baseColor"), 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "envMap"), 1); // change
    glBindVertexArray(_vao);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1); // add
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, _texture); // add
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, _normals.size());
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // add
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_NV_shadow_samplers_cube : enable
in vec4 position;
in vec3 normal;
out vec4 out_color;
uniform vec4 baseColor;
uniform samplerCube envMap;
...
void main()
{
    out_color = vec4(textureCube(envMap, vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)).rgb, 1.0);
}
```

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCd6D.png)

Comment: The default minification filter uses mipmaps. When no mipmaps are generated samplers will return black.

Comment: Your `bool complateLoadCubeMapNegY = posy.load(("D:/negy.jpg"));` lines are repeating, looks like they was copy-pasted and not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding _texture as a uniform (envMap) but that uniform should contain a texture unit. Also I don't see you binding the _texture when rendering (missing `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, _texture);`)

Also, you're not setting sampler parameters when creating the texture:

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
```